# Why generated MD5 hash in sql server are not equal?

Tags: c#, sql-server, hash, md5

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 that contain two field (WordHash, Word). This `Hash` field generated in C# and I need regenerate hash code for `Word` field in sql server.

But my problem is that generated MD5 hash in sql server and C# are different. I found below code to resolve this problem but still I have same problem.

SQL code:

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32),HASHBYTES('MD5', 'some word'), 2)
```

After putting this code block to my query, I saw some wired result! This is my result:

My Query:

```
SELECT 
    [WordHash],
    convert(nvarchar(32),HASHBYTES('MD5', 'Analytics'),2) AS TestHash,
    convert(nvarchar(32),HASHBYTES('MD5', [Word]),2) AS SqlHash
FROM myTable
```

Result:

```
WordHash: A768CAA988605A2846599CF7E2D0C26A
TestHash: A768CAA988605A2846599CF7E2D0C26A
SqlHash F4AFA5FEF805F7F5163EC6402BAF61FF
```

Note that the `'Analytics'` is one of records data in database.
Why `TestHash` & `SqlHash` are different while they generated from same code!?

Comment: If you do `N'some word'` instead of just `'some word'` do the results become the same?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I suspect that the `'Analytics'` literal and the `[Word]` value are treated with different encodings, which may indeed make a difference in the hash output.  One may be unicode while the other is not.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain you r absolutely right :). Can you post some link in order to understand why that happens?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - This question was asked earlier than the other question that you marked as duplicate. I suppose the other question should be marked duplicate than this one.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar That is not how this site works, it is not "The oldest one wins" it is "The best one wins". I found the other question and I remembered answering the same question here, I marked it duplicate to point future visitors to the better, newer, question and answer. See the meta discussion "[Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha)", the consus was: No, you should close the older one.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain- Understand now. Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue is `NVARCHAR` and `VARCHAR` get hashed to different values. Both `HASHBYTES('MD5', 'Analytics'),` and `[WordHash]` are hashes of `VARCHAR` values but `[Word]` is a `NVARCHAR`.

```
select HASHBYTES('MD5',  'Analytics'), 'varchar'
union
select HASHBYTES('MD5', N'Analytics'), 'nvarchar'

--outputs
------------------------------------- --------
0xA768CAA988605A2846599CF7E2D0C26A    varchar
0xF4AFA5FEF805F7F5163EC6402BAF61FF    nvarchar
```

To fix this you must either change `[Word]` to be `VARCHAR` or re-compute `[WordHash]` using `NVARCHAR` values.

Some useful further reading: [Comparing SQL Server HASHBYTES function and .Net hashing](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2009/04/28/Comparing-SQL-Server-HASHBYTES-function-and-.Net-hashing.aspx)

Comment: Changing query code to : `convert(nvarchar(32),HASHBYTES('MD5', convert(varchar(32),[Word])),2) AS MyHash` and It's works.

Comment: You saved our day.