# python equivalent hash for SQL query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, md5

I am generating the `md5` hash of the any given URL using the following SQL query

```
select CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),HASHBYTES('MD5',convert(nvarchar(2000),'https://alpena-mi.geebo.com/jobs-online/view/id/760191457-advanced-medical-support-assistant-/')),1)
```

Generated Hash
`0x9CA5B450B714C6C07BD1904D3080B4E4`

Can anyone tell how do I generate **same hash for any given URL using python**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For generating md5 hash you can use the hashlib library in python.
Follow sample code below

```
import hashlib
print(hashlib.md5('https://alpena-mi.geebo.com/jobs-online/view/id/760191457-advanced-medical-support-assistant-/').hexdigest())
```

The hashcode will be **5cf4fb86bb9ce08c17c54f9dba061413**

In your example, You have used nvarchar to convert the URL string.
Instead of nvarchar you can use varchar or substring to generate expected md5 hash.
For more reason: [Why generated MD5 hash in sql server are not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353446/why-generated-md5-hash-in-sql-server-are-not-equal/22354026)

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),HASHBYTES('MD5',convert(varchar(2000),'https://alpena-mi.geebo.com/jobs-online/view/id/760191457-advanced-medical-support-assistant-/')),2)

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),HASHBYTES('MD5',SUBSTRING('https://alpena-mi.geebo.com/jobs-online/view/id/760191457-advanced-medical-support-assistant-/',0,2000)),2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Python has a hashlib library. When using URLs, you need to encode it at the same time you are hashing it.

```
import hashlib

result = hashlib.sha256("https://alpena-mi.geebo.com/jobs-online/view/id/760191457-advanced-medical-support-assistant-/".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse. But I need ```0x9CA5B450B714C6C07BD1904D3080B4E4 ``` as my output